# How to concatenate columns in excel using a formula having conditions?

Tags: excel, concatenation, multiple-columns

I want to concatenate columns A, B, C and D in column E. But the concatenated cell should contain the data of all the columns with some extra text.
e.g. Suppose column A contains "11/01/1997", B contains "ABC", C contains "20" and D contains "B+". Then E should contain "DOB: (data of A column), Name: (data of B column)" and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I have misunderstood:

In the top row with data in (could be row 1 or row 2 if you have headers on the data)

Put = "DOB:" & A1 & ", Name: " & B1 ...
(Substitute 1 for 2 or whatever row you are on)

Drag this formula down the e column - this should do it for each row.

Ok?

Comment: Thank you for the reply PaulG. I tried =Concatenate("DOB:" & A1, ...) and it worked except that the value of A1 is a date but this function uses the "/"  for division operation. Any idea how to print the exact same values?

Comment: I got it now, I am using =concatenate ("DOB: " & TEXT (A1,"dd/mm/yyyy"),"Name: " & B1......).